# Where can i find last kernel compilation log?

Tags: compilation, kernel, gentoo

I've compiled custom kernel:

> (linux-3.17.4-gentoo, Linux localhost 3.17.4-gentoo #9 SMP Thu May 21 16:23:08 EEST 2015 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux)

and saw some warnings few days ago. Is there any log file where i can see them again?

Answer (score 4):

Genkernel generates a log file here /var/log/genkernel.log 
I think a log will only be made if you redirect *stdout* and *stderr* to a file, when you run the make's.

```
make > build.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Yeah but i haven't placed output to log ( . I am just wondering if there is default compilation log so  can see it. Any way I've to recompile it again with "make > build.log 2>&1" twice (deselect previous changes->compile->select them again->compile and log output). Thank You.